# Linker error when try to call ObjC method from C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, unity-game-engine

Actually, I'm a Unity developer and I know nothing about XCode and Objective C. But I have to use ObjC library for some integration and call this function from Unity. So I import that library to created XCode project and write some wrapper code between Unity and XCode. When I try to call empty function, it works for me. But when i try to write ObjC method in C file it causes linker error and I have no idea what's wrong with it. So, here's the deal:

In Unity MonoBehaviour.cs:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
public static extern void startWithAPIKey(string apiKey);
...
startWithAPIKey(apiKey);
```

In XCode Wrapper.h:

```
@interface IOSYandexMetricaWrapper : NSObject
@end
```

In XCode Wrapper.m:

```
#import "YandexMobileMetrica.h" //library header
#import "IOSYandexMetricaWrapper.h"

void startWithAPIKey(char *apiKey) {
    //method that i want to call
    [YMMYandexMetrica startWithAPIKey:(NSString *)apiKey];
}
```

So it compiles, but linker says something like this:
`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_YMMYandexMetrica", referenced from: objc-class-ref in IOSYandexMetricaWrapper.o`

Someone can help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes be caused because `YMMYandexMetrica` hasn't been included in your target.

To tell if it is included in your target, press on the `YMMYandexMetrica.m` file in the Navigator and open the Utilities side bar. You should see a subsection called "Target Membership" - the tickbox beside your project's name should be ticked.

Some more details about this issue can be here:

http://williamboles.me/_objc_class__-errors/

(It's a little out of date as it's for Xcode 4 but I think still relevant for your issue)

Comment: Thx for your reply but i have to use CocoaPods and target library is in other Project. This project builds some static library and it already included in Target Membership in my main project. So it doesn't help me yet. Maybe you'll have some other advices. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `YMMYandexMetrica` to your projects build phase setting :)